# Using R complete -X POST in command line tool curl

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I use the command line tool curl to post data and get response from server, the command is like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/gpx+xml' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary @gpslog.gpx "http://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/?app_id=MY_APPID&app_key=MY_APPKEY" -o output.json
```

I tried using RCurl package to do the same thing, but it doesn't work. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

```
postForm(uri = "http://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch/?app_id=MYID&app_key=MYKEY",
    .ops = list(httpheader = c('Content-type': 'application/gpx','Accept': 'application/json')),
    .params = "/Users/data.gpx")
```

Comment: You might want to remove the actual ID and key from this post.

Comment: @DunderChief, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `httr` - not tested, you may have to tweak it a bit

```
url <- "http://test.roadmatching.com/rest/mapmatch"
args <- list(app_id = "MY_APPID", app_key = "MY_APPKEY")
gpxxml <- add_headers(`Content-Type` = "application/gpx+xml")
httr::POST(url, query = args, gpxxml, accept_json(), 
           write_disk("output.json"), body = upload_file("gpslog.gpx"))
```

Comment: I think that may need a named `body=upload_file("gpslog.gpx")` and `accept_json()` might be easier than the `Accept`. either way +1 (I've been meaning to write a `curl` command line decoder to R `httr` or R `curl` since these come up so much.)